# To switch from vertical split to horizontal split fast in Vim

Tags: vim, split

**How can you switch your current windows from horizontal split to vertical split and vice versa in Vim?**

I did that a moment ago by accident but I cannot find the key again.

Comment: perhaps [dwm.vim](https://github.com/spolu/dwm.vim) plugin will be kinda useful

Comment: `Ctrl-w` `Shift-j`

Answer (score 1072, accepted):

[Vim mailing list](http://www.mail-archive.com/vim@vim.org/msg11206.html) says (re-formatted for better readability):

> To change *two* vertically split
>   windows to horizonally split
>
> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd> <kbd>t</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd> <kbd>K</kbd>
>
> Horizontally to vertically:
>
> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd> <kbd>t</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd> <kbd>H</kbd>
>
> Explanations:
>
> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd> <kbd>t</kbd>     makes the first (topleft) window current
>
> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd> <kbd>K</kbd>     moves the current window to full-width at the very top
>
> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd> <kbd>H</kbd>     moves the current window to full-height at far left

Note that the t is lowercase, and the K and H are uppercase.

Also, with only two windows, it seems like you can drop the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd> <kbd>t</kbd> part because if you're already in one of only two windows, what's the point of making it current?

Comment: So if you have two windows split horizontally, and you are in the lower window, you just use ^WL.

Comment: .... The power... My vim-fu doubled today, thank you.  There are a ton of interesting ^w commands (b, w, etc)

Comment: Would be nice is this worked when using the NERDTree plugin :-)

Comment: Nice one. Thanks.
Seems to work find though without making the top window active.

Comment: @Eno Works fine for me. Just toggle your NERDTree panel closed before 'rotating' the splits, then toggle it back open. :NERDTreeToggle (I have it mapped to a function key for convenience).

Comment: I have added some leader mappings to my vim config:  `:nmap <leader>th <C-w>t<C-w>H` and `:nmap <leader>tk <C-w>t<C-w>K`

Comment: In case anyone is wondering (like me) why `K` and `H`:  Those are the **Vim-Movements**, you already know. Maybe I am the only stupid one here who didn't realized, but at least you know now :)

Comment: Continuing Pixelbog's thought, Vim-Movements `J` and `L` work as you would expect here too. `J` moves the current window to full-width at the bottom, `L` moves the current window to full-height at the right.

Answer (score 435):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd> followed by <kbd>H</kbd>, <kbd>J</kbd>, <kbd>K</kbd> or <kbd>L</kbd> (capital) will move the current window to the far `left`, `bottom`, `top` or `right` respectively like normal cursor navigation.

The lower case equivalents move focus instead of moving the window.

Comment: it's much better since users use hjkl to move between buffers.

Comment: The accepted answer is a good one, but for me, this answer is easier to remember.  Thanks!

Comment: Works better with nerdtree too.

Comment: It works for me on macOS by prefixing `Ctrl`-`w` (I don't know if `^` means `Ctrl` in your example).

Comment: @GiovanniBenussi yes, I think `^` means `Ctrl`.

Answer (score 57):

When you have two *or more* windows open horizontally or vertically and want to switch them *all* to the other orientation, you can use the following:

(switch to horizontal)

```
:windo wincmd K
```

(switch to vertical)

```
:windo wincmd H
```

It's effectively going to each window individually and using <kbd>^W</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> or <kbd>^W</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>.

Answer (score 36):

The following ex commands will (re-)split any number of windows:

- To split vertically (e.g. make vertical dividers between windows), type `:vertical ball`
- To split horizontally, type `:ball`

If there are hidden buffers, issuing these commands will also make the hidden buffers visible.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, as the current accepted answer will only work for two files. This answer is more complete.

Comment: `:vert[ical] ball` in the doc so `:vert ball` is also ok and shorter.

Comment: `:ball` reduces 3 vertical windows to 2 horizontal windows, while `:vert ball`  correctly maps 3 horizontal windows to 3 vertical ones.

Comment: @DrStrangepork, it work on all open buffers instead of what is in split'ed windows. For eg: think that you are viewing 3 files in split'ed window out of 10 open buffers. Please see `:ls` for open buffers. Anyways, I like this answer along with other answers. +1

Answer (score 29):

> ## Horizontal to vertical split
>
> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> for window command,
>
> followed by <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>

---

> ## Vertical to horizontal split
>
> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> for window command,
>
> followed by <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>

Both solutions apply when only two windows exist.

After issuing the window command <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>, one is basically moving the window in the direction indicated by <kbd>Shift</kbd>+direction letter.

---

### Opening help in a vertical split by default

Add both of these lines to `.vimrc`:

```
cabbrev help vert help
cabbrev h vert h
```

`cabbrev` stands for command abbreviation.

`:vert[ical] {cmd}` always executes the `cmd` in a vertically split window.

Answer (score 27):

In VIM, take a look at the following to see different alternatives for what you might have done:

:help opening-window

For instance:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd> <kbd>s</kbd>
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd> <kbd>o</kbd>
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd> <kbd>v</kbd>
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd> <kbd>o</kbd>
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd> <kbd>s</kbd>
...

Answer (score 8):

Inspired by Steve answer, I wrote simple function that toggles between vertical and horizontal splits for all windows in current tab. You can bind it to mapping like in the last line below.

```
function! ToggleWindowHorizontalVerticalSplit()
  if !exists('t:splitType')
    let t:splitType = 'vertical'
  endif

  if t:splitType == 'vertical' " is vertical switch to horizontal
    windo wincmd K
    let t:splitType = 'horizontal'

  else " is horizontal switch to vertical
    windo wincmd H
    let t:splitType = 'vertical'
  endif
endfunction

nnoremap <silent> <leader>wt :call ToggleWindowHorizontalVerticalSplit()<cr>
```

Comment: Works even better for me if I force it to stay in the same split like so
`if winnr() == 1
        windo wincmd J
        windo wincmd k
    else
        windo wincmd J
    endif
`
and
`if winnr() == 1
        windo wincmd L
        windo wincmd h
    else
        windo wincmd L
    endif`
Hope that make sense.

Answer (score 6):

Following Mark Rushakoff's tip [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1269631/232485), here is my mapping:

```
" vertical to horizontal ( | -> -- )
noremap <c-w>-  <c-w>t<c-w>K
" horizontal to vertical ( -- -> | )
noremap <c-w>\|  <c-w>t<c-w>H
noremap <c-w>\  <c-w>t<c-w>H
noremap <c-w>/  <c-w>t<c-w>H
```

*Edit:* use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd> <kbd>r</kbd> to swap two windows if they are not in the good order.

Answer (score 0):

Coming across this in 2023, where both vim & neovim provides the built-in [`winlayout()`](https://neovim.io/doc/user/builtin.html#winlayout()) function, which returns the structure of your windows as a tree. This can be parsed and manipulated in any way one wishes, and then reapplied to render the transformed layout, by doing something outlined in [this Vi & Vim answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/22543/parsing-winlayout-for-toggling-multiple-windows-at-once/22545#22545).

Motivated by this same use case, I also extracted from my own config a small plugin called [ventana.nvim](https://github.com/jyscao/ventana.nvim), which others might find convenient to use too.