# How to change split orientation of 2 of 3 panes in vim?

Tags: vim

It's clear how I would go about changing the orientation from a vertical split to horizontal with 2 panes, but I'm curious if it's possible to do it when I have 3 or more panes. Consider the following window setup:

```
+-----------------+
|Nerd |   |   |   |
|Tree | 1 | 2 | 3 |
|     |   |   |   |
+-----------------+
```

So, in this setup, you can see I'm focused on 3 vertically split panes. However, I would like to "rotate" 2 and 3 to use a horizontal split instead, thus resulting in something like the following:

```
+-----------------+
|Nerd |     |  2  |
|Tree |  1  |-----|
|     |     |  3  |
+-----------------+
```

Is something like this possible?

Comment: Similar post: [How do I toggle between a Vertical and a Horizontal split in vimdiff?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5682759/438329). However I am going to say I have rarely had the need for 4 splits open at any one time for any length of time. I find that I am a very simple person and can only do about 2 splits at a time (3 occasionally!). This might be a good time to wean yourself off of having NerdTree open so much

Comment: Hi, thanks Peter. I understand the comment about having NerdTree open, but I feel this scenario is pretty common--in my case, I am working on a reusable widget that contains a JS, CSS, and template file. I suppose I could switch buffers and whatnot to avoid the visual burden.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. focus `2` then `:hide`
2. focus `3` then `:sp 2`  (`2` here should be filename, or `:sb (2's buf number)` )

demo:

[image]

Comment: Don't you mean `:sb` for the buffer number case?

Comment: @PeterRincker yes, if referencing buffer number, it should be `sb`

Comment: Nice visual demonstration. Appreciate it.

Comment: @kent how did you create that screencast? I know there are lots of internet,but just wanted to know which one you use.

Comment: @mtk I used `byzanz`, and wrote a wrapper to make it easy to use: https://github.com/sk1418/myScripts/blob/master/shell/recWin.sh

Answer (score 1):

In each window, CTRL-W J will move it to a horizontally split window at the bottom. Then CTRL-W H on the NERD Tree window to move it vertical left.

I have not found a better way, unfortunately. This method scales very poorly.