# How to flip windows in vim?

Tags: vim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [To switch from vertical split to horizontal split fast in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269603/to-switch-from-vertical-split-to-horizontal-split-fast-in-vim)

If I have 2 horizontally split windows, how to rotate them to get 2 vertically split windows?

And how to switch buffers?

Comment: Switch *buffers*? Or *windows*?

Comment: @Johnsyweb switch buffers, rotate windows. But I got it...

Answer (score 300, accepted):

If you have them split vertically <kbd>C-w</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> to move one to the bottom

If you have them split horizontally <kbd>C-w</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> to move one to the right

To rotate in a 'column' or 'row' of split windows, <kbd>C-w</kbd><kbd>C-r</kbd>

> The following commands can be used to change the window layout.  For example,
>   when there are two vertically split windows, CTRL-W K will change that in
>   horizontally split windows.  CTRL-W H does it the other way around.

Comment: I'm finally starting to "feel". Amazing how long I have survived w/o these commands.

Comment: To rotate split windows, I believe you only actually need "C-w r", not "C-w C-r".

Comment: @TomLord That works too. Although that's not needing "less". It's just different. And I happen to think "C-w r" is a bit awkward (especially if repeated)

Comment: @AmagicalFishy It's just `wincmd` with cursor key mnemonics: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/windows.html#:wincmd

Comment: Doesn't work properly for 4 windows open - rather than flip the windows vertically or horizonally with one another, it pushes the window to a separate level in either direction. For 2, "C-w x" is sufficient

Comment: Reading the `:help CTRL-W_K` helped me remember the keybinds after reading the description of what the keybinds are really doing.

Answer (score 104):

<kbd>Ctrl-w</kbd> <kbd>H</kbd> or type `:wincmd H` to go from **horizontal to vertical** layout.

<kbd>Ctrl-w</kbd> <kbd>J</kbd> or type `:wincmd J` to go from **vertical to horizontal** layout.

<kbd>Ctrl-w</kbd> <kbd>r</kbd> or type `:wincmd r` to **swap the two buffers** but keep the window layout the same.

<kbd>Ctrl-w</kbd> <kbd>w</kbd> or type `:wincmd w` to **move the cursor** between the two windows/buffers.

You may wish to bind one or more of these sequences to make it faster to type. I put this in my .vimrc so that <kbd>,</kbd><kbd>l</kbd> moves the cursor to the next buffer in the current tab:

```
let mapleader = ","
nmap <Leader>l <C-w>w
```

Comment: @Nick The first two really answer the question and the second two go above and beyond, which is incredibly useful! The "swap" function is particularly useful for me when I translate documents, because I prefer having source languages always on a specific side and I do not always open them in that order :)

Comment: `Ctrl-w` `r` is the best!

Comment: Big respect for showing the actual commands to remap this properly.

Answer (score 19):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd> <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>H</kbd> will rotate the orientation, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd> <kbd>H</kbd> moves to the left window, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd> <kbd>L</kbd> moves to the right. See

```
:help split
```

and

```
:help ^w
```

for more information.

Comment: That one is for switching buffers. How to change direction of windows?

Comment: @Arnis  ^wH will change the orientation of the window layout.  ^wh moves to the window on the left.  The operations are case sensitive.

Comment: AWESOME! I Love it <C-w>H and <C-w>L

Answer (score 10):

The current answers all work great if you only have two windows open. If you have more than that, the logic for moving windows around can get hairy.

I have this in my .vimrc to allow me to 'yank' and 'delete' a buffer and then paste it into a window over the current buffer or as a [v]split.

```
fu! PasteWindow(direction) "{{{
    if exists("g:yanked_buffer")
        if a:direction == 'edit'
            let temp_buffer = bufnr('%')
        endif

        exec a:direction . " +buffer" . g:yanked_buffer

        if a:direction == 'edit'
            let g:yanked_buffer = temp_buffer
        endif
    endif
endf "}}}

"yank/paste buffers
:nmap <silent> <leader>wy  :let g:yanked_buffer=bufnr('%')<cr>
:nmap <silent> <leader>wd  :let g:yanked_buffer=bufnr('%')<cr>:q<cr>
:nmap <silent> <leader>wp :call PasteWindow('edit')<cr>
:nmap <silent> <leader>ws :call PasteWindow('split')<cr>
:nmap <silent> <leader>wv :call PasteWindow('vsplit')<cr>
:nmap <silent> <leader>wt :call PasteWindow('tabnew')<cr>
```

Comment: not sure how your function is working - perhaps add a simple visual example

Comment: This is brilliant. Much better than `C-W J` and friends. I would extend it with `<leader>wP` to `top split` and `<leader>wV` to `:set nosplitright \| call PasteWindow('vsplit') \| set splitright<cr>`. And `<leader>wr` makes more sense ('replace') than `<leader>we`.