# Opening different files horizontally in vim when they're already opened vertically (without closing the document)

Tags: vim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [To switch from vertical split to horizontal split fast in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269603/to-switch-from-vertical-split-to-horizontal-split-fast-in-vim)

My version control system opened three files vertically in vim.  Is there a way to change the split to horizontal without closing the document?

Comment: Possible useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269603/to-switch-from-vertical-split-to-horizontal-split-fast-in-vim

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should fix you up.

```
Ctrl-W t Ctrl-W K 
Ctrl-W w Ctrl-W K
```